# How to filter on a json column for a specific value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm on postgres and have a table `orders` with a `data` column which is jsonb.  Here's a condensed example of data in one of them - they have UUID keys and a value of `{ id, value }`

```
  {
    '36462bd9-4ffa-4ee3-9a04-c2eb7575fe6c': {
      id: '',
      value: '2020-04-20T01:32:14.017Z',
    },
    '9baaed61-1275-4bbc-ae4f-2994ec9f7fda': { id: '4', value: 'Paper Towels' },
  }
```

How can I do operations such as to find any orders where `data` has some UUID (ie. `9baaed61-1275-4bbc-ae4f-2994ec9f7fda`) and `{ id: '4' }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from the_table
where data @> '{"9baaed61-1275-4bbc-ae4f-2994ec9f7fda": {"id": "4"}}';
```

---

This assumes that the invalid JSON `id: '4'` from your question is really stored as `"id":"4"`. If the value is stored as a number: `"id": 4` then you need to use that in the comparison value.